# .hover not working when the mouse leaves

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

When the mouse hovers over an anchor `.I1` , I want to do this:

```
$("html").css("background","url(Photos/8143009-exterior06.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed");
$(".opacity").css("opacity", "0.7");
```

And when the mouse leaves to do this:

```
$("html").css("background","");
$(".opacity").css("opacity", "1"); 
//which is the same as going back to what it was before it's hovered
```

---

Here is what I have, which doesn't work:

#### HTML

```
<a class="I1" href="Photos/8143009-exterior06.jpeg">
    <img src="Photos/8143009-exterior06.jpeg" alt="" width="297" height="200" />
</a>
```

#### JS :

```
$(".I1").hover(function(){
    $("html").css("background","url(Photos/8143009-exterior06.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed");
    $(".opacity").css("opacity", "0.7");
});
```

I want to do this for each photo, in a displayed row of photos.

Is there also a quicker way to do that, rather than having to write the script for each photo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation about `hover()` states this  ([see reference](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)):

> .hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )

You are calling a custom function when the mouse enters (first parameter of `hover()`), and not when it leaves (second parameter).

So, you might change your code for this:

```
$(".I1").hover(function(){
     $("html").css("background","url(Photos/8143009-exterior06.jpeg) no-repeat center center fixed");
     $(".opacity").css("opacity", "0.7");
},function(){
     $("html").css("background","");
     $(".opacity").css("opacity", "1")
});
```

### Edit

I think it's better for you to stick with my proposition, it's not *that* much longer.

Without more information about what you're trying to achieve, here's my guess: *you'll have multiple `.I1`, and as you were about to code it, it would have been very long to copy / paste this `hover` function for each elements and put the right picture link in each.* (correct me if I'm wrong)

What I propose you to do, is extracting the link of your picture, and use it as your `html` background (and so, whatever the hovered element, the background will adapt).

```
$(".I1").hover(function() {        
     var imageToPrint = 'url(' + $('img',this).attr('src') +')';
     $("html").css("background", imageToPrint + "no-repeat center center fixed");
     $(".opacity").css("opacity", "0.7");
},function(){
     $("html").css("background","transparent");
     $(".opacity").css("opacity", "1")
});
```

[Here's a fiddle for demonstration.](http://jsfiddle.net/KSH58/)

Comment: check doc, here OP is using in/out handler sig `.hover( handlerInOut(eventObject) )` But i guess it is correct ansumption, OP is confusing mouseover with hover

Comment: @Bigood Is there a way to remove the second part of the code `,function(){ $("html").css("background",""); $(".opacity").css("opacity", "1")` and make it just go back to the original

Comment: @user2768038 I propose you to stick with my original answer, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/.

They are doing just the thing you want but they are changing the text in the divs ( look at the example at the bottom) and you need to change the background.

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //When mouse rolls over
    $(".I1").bind('mouseover mouseenter', function() {
        //do stuff
    });

    //When mouse is removed
    $(".I1").bind('mouseout mouseleave', function() {
        //do stuff
    });
```

Might use this. :)